# room upgrade database exception

Tags: android, android-room

I recently updated the database version, and i wrote a migration block for this. Also i tested so many times and there was no problem. But i pushed the update to play store then i am getting some crash reports about that db update:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run (RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
  at .Caused
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:124)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:338)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:476)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:281)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query (RoomDatabase.java:324)
  at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query (DBUtil.java:83)
  at com.impact.ribony.persistance.UserDao_Impl$25.call (UserDao_Impl.java:965)
  at com.impact.ribony.persistance.UserDao_Impl$25.call (UserDao_Impl.java:962)
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run (RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
```

There is no error message, so i can't figured out the problem.

**This is my migration block:**

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE conversations ADD lastMessageLocalTime INTEGER");
database.execSQL("UPDATE conversations SET lastMessageLocalTime = lastMessageTime");
```

*Also `lastMessageTime` field is Integer*

What is the problem?

Comment: I got the same error with my app on play store. My upgrade strategy was destructive (i.e fallbacktodestructive migration).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing 'COLUMN' after 'ADD'

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE conversations ADD COLUMN lastMessageLocalTime INTEGER");
```

Comment: Hmm how my tests on emulator did pass then?

Comment: Good question. Did you do a migration unit test according to the Room docs?

Comment: No i just testes on different emulators and android versions

Comment: How did you test the migration on the emulator? Installing newer version through adb?

Comment: No, i am using Genymotion as emulator, it supports drag & drop apk files on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208927/discussion-between-nulldroid-and-tolgay-toklar).

Comment: I don't think the migration block is the source of this error. I got the same error with my app having a destructive upgrade strategy.